# What is Hinduism's stand on bestiality?

Tags: scripture, sin, animals

[Bestiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoophilia_and_the_law) is possibly the most abnormal and perverted form of sexual intercourse where a human being unites (sexually) with an animal.

Presumably, some [Hindu temples](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-Indian-erotic-temple-art-depict-bestiality) in India depict bestiality through sculptures found on their walls.

Now, based on that some people may jump on to conclusion **that "Hinduism" supports/promotes it.**

What do the Hindu Scriptures say on bestiality. Since it's called  the "Sanatana Dharma" we can expect that it will not avoid it by saying too vulgar/taboo/offensive to discus and will have a definite say/stand on the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by unnatural here? Because if you're using the common meaning of the word ("found in nature"), there is nothing unnatural about it.

Comment: By "unnatural" I meant something which is against natural order/laws."Found in nature" and "supported by natural laws" are two different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm adding my own answer based on the [Parashara Smriti](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/13Parashara_Smriti.pdf).Looking for more answers from other users with valid Scriptural quotes.

Chapter 10 of Parashara Smriti is titled *Agamyaagamanaprayaschittavarnanam* or "The description of expiations for prohibited sexual intercourses".

This chapter deals with bestiality too.Slokas 12 &13 are useful here.

> 12. On carnal intercourse with a beast, or a prostitute and the like, or with a female buffalo, or with a female camel, or with a she
>       monkey, or with a sow, or a female ass, one should perform the
>       Prajapatya penance.

[image]

> 13. On carnal intercourse with a cow, the sin is removed by three nights' fast; a cow should be presented to a Brahman as fee. On carnal
>       connection with a female buffalo, a female camel or an ass, the sin is
>       removed by one night's fast.

[image]

Similarly, the Manu Smriti(Chapter 11 verse 173), states:

> 11.173. **A man who has committed a bestial crime**, or an unnatural crime with a female, or has had intercourse in water, or with a menstruating
>   woman, shall perform a Samtapana Krikkhra.

[image]

So,as per Hindu Shastras, bestiality is  a sin and the expiations are also precisely mentioned therein.

Comment: Why do certain temples have homosexual and bestial acts carved on their walls? What do they represent?

Comment: They are an acknowledgement of some people practicing bestiality at that time. There would have been no need for these smritis to prescribe prayaschitta if nobody practiced it.

Comment: How can I know that? I did not build those temples @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury. Yudhistira lied to win a battle, he betted his wife, Bhima drank blood of his brother.. What do these incidents show? that they have approval of Dharma?

Answer (score 7):

The Vishnu Smriti condemns bestial acts:

> Causing (bodily) pain to a Brāhmaṇa; smelling at things which ought not to be smelt (such as excrements), or at spirituous liquor; dishonest dealing; **sexual connection with cattle**, and (sexual connection) with a man (or non-vaginal intercourse with a woman): **such are the crimes resulting in loss of caste. He who has knowingly committed one of the acts effecting loss of caste shall perform the Sântapana penance; he who has done so unawares shall perform the Prâgâpatya penance.** (**Vishnu Smriti, Chapter 38, Verses 1-6**)

The Narada Smriti too explicitly forbids bestial acts:

> **When a man has sexual connection with (small) cattle, he shall pay one hundred (Panas) as a fine; (for sexual connection) with a cow, he shall pay the middling fine**; and the same (for sexual connection) with a low-caste woman. (**Narada Smriti 12.76**)