# Relations with Cows?

Tags: scripture, smriti, cows, sex

........."The Atri Smriti also mentions homosexuality as a sin and prescribes an expiation measure for the same:

> **By discharging semen into inhuman females except a cow**, into a woman in [her] menses, into others that have no female organs (i.e., a man or a eunuch), or into water one should perform the penance of Santapanam.
>
> (Atri Smriti, Chapter 1, Verse 268)"...........

[Taken from Rickross' [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/vedas-and-vedic-dharma-on-homosexuality/15520#15520)]

Why a man should not be discharging semen in inhuman females "except for cow"? Can a man discharge semen in a cow?

Comment: BTW here is a related post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15478/what-is-hinduisms-stand-on-bestiality

Comment: Mr Anurag Singh who discharge semen in the Mother? I request all of you to flag this question down

Comment: @Rishi i think his question is genuine though it looks as rude as Cow is sacred for us. Anurag, you can edit it a bit or add **note** mentioning no offense.

Comment: @Rishi You never know. The perverts can do anything.

Comment: @Rishi I do not intend to do put up some abusive talks. I just asked- why would Atri say that we should not discharge semen in any inhuman female other than cow. I do not mean that I want to do the same, I disgust this. Instead of protesting to close the question, ask and argue why this would be written in our Scriptures. I know that it is not promoted like a festival, but why would this still not even be condemned- not discharging semen in any inhuman female , except for cow.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I do never mean any offense here. And I am not like a wanton brute who would like to talk dirty things here. And thank you that you understood it.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Well I only believe in Vedas, Manu Smriti and Upnishads. I am sorry because when i saw Rickross answer it is said that but again my friend this is India and Riots happens in the name of Dharma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is forbidden.  Intercourse with all animals is forbidden, it's just that the Prayaschitta required is more arduous in the case of a cows than in the case of another animal.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=MC-IK69vF84C&dq=%22into%20inhuman%20females%20except%20a%20cow%22&pg=PA318#v=onepage&q&f=false) is what the Atri Smriti says in context:

> Prajapatya is laid down for holding sexual intercourse with a beast, or with a harlot. **By holding intercourse with a cow, one should perform a Chandrayana spoken of by Manu.** By discharging semen into inhuman females except a cow, into a woman in [her] menses, into others that have no female organs (i.e., a man or a eunuch), or into water one should perform the penance of Santapanam.

Comment: Oh. So this was all the case of misinterpretation. I should have read the preceding verses also . Keshav thank you so much. You are really so great.

Comment: @AnuragSingh You're welcome.  If I've satisfactorily answered your question, you should click the accept check mark.

Answer (score 6):

Oh ok just now realised what you are actually  asking. What Atri Smriti is saying is , that (santapana) is the punishment for having unnatural sexual intercourse with any female animals except a cow.

In case of a similar offence against a cow, the punishment is even more severe. And this is mentioned in just the previous verse of the same chapter. I am giving both the verses here.

> Prajapatya is- laid down for holding sexual intercourse with a beast,
>   or with a harlot. **By holding intercourse with a cow, one should
>   perform- a Chandrayana spoken of by Manu.** (267)
>
> By discharging semen into inhuman females except a cow, into a woman
>   in [her] menses, into others that have no female organs ( a man
>   or a eunuch), or into water one should perform the penance of
>   Santapanam. (268)
>
> **Atri smriti, Chapter 1, Verses 267, 268.**

Santapana is relatively a lot  easy to perform. Whereas, Chandrayana is a much more difficult prayaschitta or penance which involves prolonged fasting.

**Definitions of Chandrayana and Samtapana penances from Manu Smriti are given below:**

> 11.212. (Subsisting on) the urine of cows, cowdung, milk, sour milk, clarified butter, and a decoction of Kusagrass, and fasting during one
>   (day and) night, (that is) called a Samtapana Krikkhra.
>
> 11.216. If one diminishes (one’s food daily by) one mouthful during the dark (half of the month) and increases (it in the same manner)
>   during the bright half, and bathes (daily) at the time of three
>   libations (morning, noon, and evening), that is called a lunar penance
>   (Chandrayana).

Comment: Yes I now understood. It was all misinterpretation due to not studying preceding verses. Even I was thinking- how could our Scriptures say not to discharge semen in any inhuman female other than cow. Rickross thank you for your explanations.

Comment: so at last you got what I was trying to ask. ;)

Comment: @AnuragSingh Actually in the evening it came to my mind and then i searched in Atri Smriti. Initially i completely misunderstood ur question. But i also have a bad habit of not going through a post thoroughly. And that's why i often find myself in trouble on internet forums :D